# Application with wrong code even after a git force push

Tags: node.js, git, ibm-cloud

I am under the impression that my application on Bluemix is running an older (wrong) version of the code. I have made several updates and now the application doesn't deploy nor will it start. When I check the log files, I see some errors due to Express middleware changes that are no longer supported and should be replaced by external components, for example, replace bodyParser with body-parser. I have made all these changes replacing express.middlewarename with the new components according to this page: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

However, I am still getting error messages in the log file when I try to deploy the application. The message is:

```
throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled with 
Express and must be installed separately. Please see 
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.');
2017/4/5 午後2時42分48秒 ERR APP at Function.Object.defineProperty.get 
(/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:107:13)
2017/4/5 午後2時42分48秒 ERR APP at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
2017/4/5 午後2時42分48秒 ERR APP at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
2017/4/5 午後2時42分48秒 ERR APP at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

I am able to run the application on my machine. If I download the code from the compile pipeline, it seems fine. However, I see some errors, which point to a line of code that is a comment or a blank line in my files.
All of these issues leads me to believe that Bluemix is trying to deploy a wrong version of code.
Does anyone know how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to guess if it has old code - you can 'cf ssh AppName' and check. I have to do a deploy from hub.jazz.net to get the changes to production.

Comment: cf ssh is not working right now, for some reason I get the following
SSH session allocation failed: ssh: unexpected packet in response to channel open: <nil>
I am using hub.jazz.net for the build pipeline and deploy, is there a way to force the compile/build and deploy jobs to get the latest version of the code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have make sure your all node process is killed.

On linux you can check using : ps aux|grep node.

After that rebuild your npm. using "npm build" command.

Start you server it will work.

Comment: Ok but how to do it on bluemix? It should be automatic, in fact I do believe it does it all but looks like using an older (very old) version of the code.
I am looking for a way to force bluemix to pull the last version of the code from git.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things
 1. Add a git commit tag as apart of your end point. Maven and other build tools have this capability and it good practice especially for micro service architectures. Spring has one and I would be surprised if node didn't have something similar. This is what I found with a brief search. [1]
 2. Trying doing a cf d ${app_name} then re-push your app.
 3. If you're using a manifest file or using the cf p command make sure you specify the path to the application being deployed. There are some other nuances with node on CF but you can also assign start scripts to the build pack when the app is being deployed.

I hope this helps.

[1] https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/